# How do I fix my unity play button script? it was working before

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I fix this it was working before but it broke somehow: (Solved)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SM_SceneSwitcher : MonoBehaviour {
  public void playGame()
    {
     SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1); 
    }
    public void Back()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1);
    }
```

Comment: Broke how? Is there an error? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your script is not attached to the game object anymore ?

This happens if you rename or move your script, your button still references the old path, you need to put your script again in your button

This, or the playGame and Back functions are not assigned to the click action.

Comment: I just found out there was a error the error is: Assets/MainMenu/Scripts/SM_SceneSwitcher.cs(14,6): error CS1513: } expected

Comment: Indeed, there is a missing bracket at the end, to close your class.